# Jenkins unable to fetch changeId and revisionId

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have configured and integrated Jenkins and Gerrit with Gerrit Trigger Plugin and as part of postbuild task in Jenkins i am executing following script:

```
/opt/sputnik/bin/sputnik --conf /opt/sputnik/myconf.properties --changeId $GERRIT_CHANGE_ID --revisionId $GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION
echo "exit 0 workaround"
```

Here is what sputnik is:https://github.com/TouK/sputnik

But Iam getting following output:

```
[PostBuildScript] - Execution post build scripts.
[PostBuildScript] - Resolving environment variables for the script content.
[PostBuildScript] - Evaluating the script: 
/var/lib/jenkins/sputnik/bin/sputnik --conf /var/lib/jenkins/sputnik/gerrit.properties --changeId $GERRIT_CHANGE_ID --revisionId $GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION
echo "exit 0 workaround"

[project1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6990025050616459512.sh
+ /var/lib/jenkins/sputnik/bin/sputnik --conf /var/lib/jenkins/sputnik/gerrit.properties --changeId --revisionId
Sputnik version 1.7.0
Sputnik - review your Gerrit patchset with Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs
usage: sputnik [--apiKey <apiKey>] [--buildId <buildId>] [--changeId <changeId>] --conf <conf> [--pullRequestId
   <pullRequestId>] [--revisionId <revisionId>]
--apiKey <apiKey>                 Optional API key for using Sputnik for Github
--buildId <buildId>               Optional build id for using Sputnik for Github
--changeId <changeId>             Gerrit change id
--conf <conf>                     Configuration properties file
--pullRequestId <pullRequestId>   Stash pull request id
--revisionId <revisionId>         Gerrit revision id
Missing argument for option: changeId
Build step 'Execute a set of scripts' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Execute a set of scripts' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You are using Sputnik on the wrogn way, see output. **changeId** and **revisionId** need a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by [this security patch](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34753) for Jenkins - it applies to versions `1.651.2`, `2.3` and later.
Here's a [list of affected plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170).

Basically it forbids plugins to inject parameters not explicitly configured for build, hence your Jenkins doesn't know about `$GERRIT_CHANGE_ID` and `$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION`.

According to [Gerrit Trigger Plugin creators' notice](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-Importantnotice):

> As a workaround you can add the following JAVA_ARG to your jenkins configuration
>
> `-Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true`

However, I find this solution too invasive so I came up with another fix. Simply add these string parameters to the job configuration:

- GERRIT_CHANGE_ID
- GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION

And that's it. Now your config should look like this:

[image: Job parameters]